# Junk Chars in FileName

Tags: java, file, encoding, io, character

We occasionally get files in the Unix file system with few junk characters in the file name. This is a result of improper encoding by the upstream component, which creates these files. There is a java program which is trying to read this file - Is there any way for the java code to read the contents of this file with few garbage characters? Apart from few junk characters, most of the characters are good in the file name. Currently it give the  "File Not found" error.

Comment: You need to supply more detail about the actual errant characters.  A common case is where some code mistakenly assumes a UTF-8 representation is actually a one-byte-per-character representation like ISO 8859-1, resulting in, for instance, `é` showing up as `Ã©`.  In this case, you can encode the String with ISO-8859-1 then decode those bytes with UTF-8.

Comment: Please provide details of code you have written. Error can't be detected like that. FileNotFound should not be there due to encoding. It may be referring wrong file name problem.

Comment: VGR Thanks, the original file is reservación.123456789.txt
The file in the directory is reservaci?n.123456789.txt or reservaci�n.123456789.txt. If i try to read the file with name "reservaci?n.123456789.txt", get a File Not Found. 
Even tried filtering files by *.123456789.txt and trying to read, still getting the same issue.